# canMoveRowAtIndexPAth and canEditRowAtIndexPath methods issue

Tags: swift, methods, tableview, edit

I had this simple app working flawlessly when I built it, but then I played around with editing rows, trying to stop the red delete circle on the left showing up while in editing mode and have only swipe action enabled, but to have move rows still there on tapping "Move" button. Now, I'm only left with swipe-delete action and move doesn't work at all, and also circles don't appear anymore (which is good). I reverted everything back to what it was before, but still no effect. Did something change in regards to that in xCode 7.2 update? Or I just messed up something, I can't put my finger on anymore?
Here is the code in question:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    title = "Password Vault"
    navigationItem.prompt = "Add entry by clicking on the '+' sign -->"
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self


    let editButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Move", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "editRows")
    let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self, action: "addEntry")

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [addButton, editButton]

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Lock", style: .Done, target: self, action: "lock")


    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor() // for Bar Buttons


}
func editRows() {
    editing = true
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems![1] = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Done, target: self, action: "finishEditingRows")
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems![0].enabled = false
}

func finishEditingRows() {
    editing = false
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems![1] = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Move", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "editRows")
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems![0].enabled = true
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let val = self.entries.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row)
    let val1 = self.usernames.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row)
    let val2 = self.passwords.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row)

    self.entries.insert(val, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)
    self.usernames.insert(val1, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)
    self.passwords.insert(val2, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return entries.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    return true
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.entries[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT", size: 30)

    cell.accessoryType = .DetailButton
    cell.textLabel?.shadowColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    cell.textLabel?.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: -2)


    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


        entries.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        usernames.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        passwords.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

        //update entriesArray after deleting entries
        saveData()

        tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Comment: Resolved the issue...

Comment: If you resolved the issue maybe you should share the answer. That's kind of the point of Stack Overflow, its a give and take.